# HTML TextBox Color Theme

Tags: html, xml, themes, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to find a way to apply color themes to the content of a textbox or a label.

Here is the effect I want to see:
[image]

Are there any tool which I can use to achieve this?

Any help will be appreciative.

Comment: This is called syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

There are some open source projects that do this, for example [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) (using Javascript).

As SLaks suggested, [you should accept answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to your questions to gain trust and support on the site.